# Way to Diff Two Word Documents With Change Tracking turned off

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone have advice on how to display the difference between two word documents? I am thinking of something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/) but for word documents and not source code. If there is built-in functionality to do this, I cannot find it. (Word 2010+)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in functionality for this in Word with some decent comparison options. In Word 2010, look on the **Review tab**, near the right, where you'll see **Compare**. Choices under there include **Compare...** and Combine...

From there, you get the **Compare Documents** dialog box, where you select the two files to compare, and have the option (under **More >>**) to fine-tune how you want to compare the documents.
[image]

For more help, check out the [BrainStorm video tutorial on Compare Documents](http://www.brainstorminc.com/microsoft-office-com-help.aspx?file=word14_23).

Comment: Hadn't noticed that. I swear I looked everywhere on that review tab. Bah! :-D